# Develop a custom file sync provider over file transfer WCF service

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework, synchronization

I'm trying to develop a custom sync provider to sync files over the internet using WCF service.

We already have a file transfer service and it's working in production but I need to implement a custom sync provider on top of it.
I've checked the solution in [Braynt Likes blog here](http://bryantlikes.com/RemoteFileSyncUsingWCFAndMSF.aspx) but this doesn't fulfill my needs.

Any advices, guidance, or sample code to help is really appreciated?

Answer (score -1):

My advice is not to write custom code when there are powerful products available, especially if they're free.

Have a look at the Microsoft Sync Framework.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx

Comment: I kinda think that's what the OP is asking about - the article he links to show how to create a custom provider for the MS Sync Framework, and he has a tag "syncframework" - so I guess that what he's after

Comment: Exactly, I'm talking about creating a custom provider for MS Sync Framework